# MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter vs. Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder

Tags: json, spring, jackson

Can anyone tell me what are the differences between these objects? When I use first one spring acts different to the second one, although they nearly configure the same.

Both are configured in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. When i should use which one to configure JSON-Serialization and JSON-Deserialization?

My code:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}



@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        builder.serializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS);
        builder.failOnEmptyBeans(false);
        builder.failOnUnknownProperties(false);
        builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in order to serialize and deserialize your JSON input. Jackson uses class `ObjectMapper` to convert JSON to Java objects and vice versa, so `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` is just a convenient class which uses Builder pattern to build `ObjectMapper` for you which can be later injected into the converter.

Comment: So `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` just specify more object mapper details'? I mean I know why and when to configure `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, but I didnt really get when to configure `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, builder is just a way how to configure `ObjectMapper` class.

Comment: But what happens, if I set an option for the builder and the same for the objectmapper. Is the objectmapper overriding? **It doesn't seems so**

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, builder will create new `ObjectMapper`, that's the purpose of this design pattern.

Comment: Just look at the source code and you will see yourself http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build%28%29